# Using traefik to route a port to another traefik instance

Tags: docker-compose, mesh, traefik, mender

I'm working with a machine with only port 443 open. I have multiple services on this machine and I am using traefik as a port forwarding system. Currently, I can operate and run my Mesh instance flawlessly (even websockets are working behind traefik!). However, I am trying to run Mender behind this as well. The issue is that Mender also uses traefik. It seems to me that the service Mender is running all well and good. I can create a user and login and such. However, I can't access it over the port 443, which is what I want to do.

Here is my docker-compose.yml for traefik now:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.8
    restart: always
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - '80:80' # http
      - '443:443' # https
      - '8080:8080' #dashboard port
    command:
      ## Provider Settings - https://docs.traefik.io/providers/docker/#provider-configuration ##
      - --providers.docker=true # Set docker as the provider for traefik
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false # You need to whitelist containers that will be exposed to traefik
      - --providers.file.filename=/dynamic.yml # Referring to the https upgrade file
      - --providers.docker.network=web # Use the docker network web for communication between traefik and containser
      ## Entrypoints Settings - https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#configuration ##
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80 # Define an entrypoint for port :80 named web (this can be whatever)
      ## Certificate Settings (Let's Encrypt) -  https://docs.traefik.io/https/acme/#configuration-examples ##
      - --certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.email=xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
        #- --entrypoints.web-secured.address=:443
      - "--api.insecure=true" # This enables the dashboard without any authentication
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
        #- --entrypoints.http.address=:80
    volumes:
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt # Volume for certs (TLS)
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # Volume for docker admin
      - ./dynamic.yml:/dynamic.yml # Volume for dynamic conf file, **ref: line 14
    networks:
      - web # Tell the container that it has access to this network

    labels:
      # enable traefik for this services
      - traefik.enable=true
      # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
      - traefik.web.services.traefik-dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTP
      - traefik.web.routers.traefik-dashboard-http.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.web.routers.traefik-dashboard-http.rule=Host(`dashboard.localhost`)
      # make traefik use this network
      - traefik.docker.network=web
        #- traefik.http.routers.mender-old.rule=Host(`mender.localhost`)
        #- traefik.http.services.mender-old.loadbalancer.server.port=8084
networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

Here is my compose file for Mender, which is quite complicated. The main service is mender-api-gateway which is using traefik:

```yaml
version: '2.1'
services:

    #
    # mender-iot-manager
    #
    mender-iot-manager:
        image: mendersoftware/iot-manager:mender-3.4.0
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
        labels:
            mender.healthcheck.path: "/api/internal/v1/iot-manager/health"

    #
    # mender-deployments
    #
    mender-deployments:
        image: mendersoftware/deployments:mender-3.4.0
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
        labels:
            mender.healthcheck.path: "/api/internal/v1/deployments/health"

    #
    # mender-gui
    #
    mender-gui:
        image: mendersoftware/gui:mender-3.4.0
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        environment:
            - GATEWAY_IP
            - INTEGRATION_VERSION
            - MENDER_ARTIFACT_VERSION
            - MENDER_VERSION
            - MENDER_DEB_PACKAGE_VERSION
            - HAVE_DEVICECONNECT=1
            - HAVE_DEVICECONFIG=1

    #
    # mender-api-gateway
    #
    mender-api-gateway:
        image: traefik:v2.8
        ports:
          - "8082:8082"
          - "8080:8080"
          - "8084:8084"
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
        command:
            - --accesslog=true
            - --entrypoints.http.address=:8082
            - --entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
            - --entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=https
            - --entrypoints.https.address=:8084
            - --entryPoints.https.transport.respondingTimeouts.idleTimeout=7200
            - --entryPoints.https.transport.respondingTimeouts.readTimeout=7200
            - --entryPoints.https.transport.respondingTimeouts.writeTimeout=7200
            - --providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik/config
            - --api.insecure=true
            - --api.dashboard=true
            - --log.level=DEBUG
            #  Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt): automatic SSL.
            - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=xxx@xxx.org"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge=true"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
            # Global redirect to https
            - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
            - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.mender-api-gateway-web.rule=Host(`mender.xxx.xxx.xxx`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.mender-api-gateway-web.entrypoints=http"
            - "traefik.http.routers.mender-api-gateway-secure.rule=Host(`mender.xxx.xxx.xxx`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.mender-api-gateway-secure.entrypoints=https"
            - "traefik.http.routers.mender-api-gateway-secure.tls.certresolver=mytlschallenge"
            - "traefik.http.services.mender-api-gateway.loadbalancer.server.port=8084"
            - "traefik.docker.network=web"
        volumes:
            # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
            # Dynamic configuration files
            - ./config/traefik/traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/config/traefik.yaml:ro
            - ./config/traefik/traefik.middlewares.yaml:/etc/traefik/config/traefik.middlewares.yaml:ro

        networks:
            - mender
            - web
        # critical - otherwise nginx may not detect
        # these servers and exits with 'upstream server not found'
        depends_on:
            - mender-device-auth
            - mender-gui
            - mender-useradm
            - mender-inventory

    #
    # mender-device-auth
    #
    mender-device-auth:
        image: mendersoftware/deviceauth:mender-3.4.0
        environment:
            DEVICEAUTH_ORCHESTRATOR_ADDR: http://mender-workflows-server:8080/
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
            - mender-workflows-server
        labels:
            mender.healthcheck.path: "/api/internal/v1/devauth/health"

    #
    # mender-inventory
    #
    mender-inventory:
        image: mendersoftware/inventory:mender-3.4.0
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
        labels:
            mender.healthcheck.path: "/api/internal/v1/inventory/health"

    #
    # mender-useradm
    #
    mender-useradm:
        image: mendersoftware/useradm:mender-3.4.0
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
        labels:
            mender.healthcheck.path: "/api/internal/v1/useradm/health"

    #
    # mender-workflows-server
    #
    mender-workflows-server:
        image: mendersoftware/workflows:mender-3.4.0
        environment:
            WORKFLOWS_MONGO_URL: mongodb://mender-mongo:27017
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
            - mender-nats
        labels:
            mender.healthcheck.path: "/health"

    #
    # mender-workflows-worker
    #
    mender-workflows-worker:
        image: mendersoftware/workflows-worker:mender-3.4.0
        command: worker --excluded-workflows generate_artifact
        environment:
            WORKFLOWS_MONGO_URL: mongodb://mender-mongo:27017
            DEVICECONNECT_ADDR: "mender-deviceconnect:8080"
            HAVE_DEVICECONNECT: 1
            HAVE_DEVICECONFIG: 1
            DEVICECONFIG_ADDR: "mender-deviceconfig:8080"
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
            - mender-nats

    #
    # mender-create-artifact-worker
    #
    mender-create-artifact-worker:
        image: mendersoftware/create-artifact-worker:mender-3.4.0
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        environment:
            - WORKFLOWS_MONGO_URL=mongodb://mender-mongo:27017
            - CREATE_ARTIFACT_GATEWAY_URL=https://mender-api-gateway
            - CREATE_ARTIFACT_DEPLOYMENTS_URL=http://mender-deployments:8080
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
            - mender-nats

    #
    # mender-deviceconnect
    #
    mender-deviceconnect:
        image: mendersoftware/deviceconnect:mender-3.4.0
        command: server --automigrate
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
            - mender-nats
        environment:
            DEVICECONNECT_MONGO_URL: "mongodb://mender-mongo"
            DEVICECONNECT_NATS_URI: "nats://mender-nats:4222"
        labels:
            mender.healthcheck.path: "/api/internal/v1/deviceconnect/health"

    #
    # mender-deviceconfig
    #
    mender-deviceconfig:
        image: mendersoftware/deviceconfig:mender-3.4.0
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            - mender
        depends_on:
            - mender-mongo
        command: server --automigrate
        labels:
            mender.healthcheck.path: "/api/internal/v1/deviceconfig/health"

    mender-mongo:
        image: mongo:4.4
        extends:
            file: common.yml
            service: mender-base
        networks:
            mender:
                aliases:
                    - mongo-tenantadm
                    - mongo-deployments
                    - mongo-device-auth
                    - mongo-inventory
                    - mongo-useradm
                    - mongo-workflows

    mender-nats:
        image: nats:2.6-alpine
        command: -js
        networks:
            - mender

networks:
    mender: null
    web:
        external: true
```

Besides the fact that Lets Encrypt ssl verification does not work at all, I can only access the service over the port which I specify (8084). I need it to work from 443. I have several other configuration files as well and I'm sure having a traefik.yml file for configurations would be better. I am just really stuck on getting the page to load over 443 now. The other service, mesh is able to fine.

I tried to make Mender be able to be accessed over port 443 and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.